# An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 403 Debugging information follows. Path: /system/ajax StatusText: Forbidden ResponseText:

Tags: ajax, panels, features

I have received this error twice, first during panels everywhere, and now again working with Features module. It is produced When you create new feature:

Structure > Features >
and click on 'Edit Components'

I have to select Content type: node
and As soon as I check on any of the check boxes of content types available on my website, I get similar error:

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 403 Debugging
>   information follows. Path: /system/ajax StatusText: Forbidden
>   ResponseText:

I am logged in as an Administrator, so have all the rights.

Hoping to find any work around soon. I am encountering this error on two different areas of the website, and it prevents me from doing any work further.

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: How can I get rid of this error.

Comment: When I checked the log messages found : Type ajax
Date Wednesday, September 26, 2012 - 23:45
User admin
Location http://example.com/system/ajax
Referrer http://example.com/admin/structure/features/create?render=overlay
Message Invalid form POST data.
Severity warningd   and another error logged in:Type php
Date Wednesday, September 26, 2012 - 23:45
User admin
Location http://xxxx/system/ajax
Referrer http://xxxx/features/create?render=overlay
Message Notice: Undefined index: form_build_id in ajax_get_form() (line 320 of xxx/includes/ajax.inc).

Comment: Could you add your comment above as a part of the question?

Answer (score -4):

It might be a file permission issue. Change them to 777.

Comment: For which file should the file permissions be changed?

Comment: It has nothing to do with file permissions and changing the file permissions to 777 is a no go.